# material design not recognize

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-routing

Here is my folder:

```
-app 
     -content
     -footer
     -header
       -main-header
         {other services - shortcut} <- I just shortcut this bec. it is too long.
         main-header.component.html
         main-header.component.scss
         main-header.component.spec.ts
         main-header.module.ts
         main-header.routing.ts
     app.component.html
     etc..
```

main-header module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MainHeaderComponent } from './main-header.component';
import { MainHeaderRouteModule } from './main-header.routing';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    FormsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MainHeaderRouteModule,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class MainHeaderModule {}
```

main-header.routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainHeaderComponent } from './main-header.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MainHeaderComponent}
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainHeaderRouteModule {}
```

app module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MainHeaderComponent } from './header/main-header/main-header.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MainHeaderComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'main-header', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Since I am using a lazyloading route, it seems that the main-module doesn't recognize angular material:

'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]

Answer (score 0):

i dont see you importing your MainHeaderModule anywhere in app.module

Comment: I tried this one and this error came up.  

ERROR in Type MainHeaderComponent in D:/Angular/proj/src/app/header/main-header/main-header.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Comment: i dont know  the structure of your code base, but i see your including in the declarations "MainHeaderComponent" in two different modules.  remove it from one of them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments for Lys's answer, you need to import MainHeaderModule in app.module.ts. Then you will get the error you mentioned

```
 ERROR in Type MainHeaderComponent in D:/Angular/proj/src/app/header/main-header/main-header.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules
```

The error is because, in both modules you have declared MainHeaderComponent. Remove MainHeaderComponent from app.module.ts. Since it's already declared in main header module. Importing main header module in app.module.ts will take care of MainHeaderComponent.